# Android Storage Locations

Tags: android, storage, android-sdcard

Can someone explain in detail about the various storage locations in Android,

1. /sdcard/ (along with /root/ directory and other system-level directory)
2. /storage/emulated/0/
3. /storage/emulated/legacy/
4. /storage/sdcard0/

Really confused with these? And are there any methods to access them programatically whenever needed?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. StackExchange network has http://superuser.com for general questions and a dedicated site for android enthusiasts : http://android.stackexchange.com/ . Try one of those (not both!).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't speak for storage paths on all phones. But I can explain you clearly with respect to my phone; Coolpad Note 3 - running on Android 5.1. Because, the storage locations or paths may vary on other mobile phones depending on your vendor/manufacturer and different versions of Android OS.

Generally, `/someDirectory` or `/root/someDirectory` or `>root>someDirectory` are same. Which among them is picked to display; depends on your file manager.

**On my phone:**

`/root/sdcard` is storage path to  **phone's internal memory**(16 GB in my case).

Both `/storage/emulated/0/` and `/storage/sdcard0/` are symlinks to `/root/sdcard`. It means, these two paths are also storage paths of my **phone's internal memory**.

`/storage/sdcard1/` is storage path of my **micro SD card**.

**On ANY phone:**

Before Android 4.2, only one user could user your phone. There was **no** concept of **two or more users** creating separate profiles and logging into the same phone.

As a result, there were no such paths like `/storage/emulated/someDirectory`

The *emulated* directories came up after the introduction of **multiuser API in Android 4.2**.

Source: [source 1](https://plus.google.com/103583939320326217147/posts/Euzxu467GrJ) and [source 2](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35541/why-did-sdcard-turn-into-sdcard-0-with-4-2)

So from then,

`/storage/emulated/legacy/` points to External Storage(Android terminology) of the currently working user. It would be a symlink.

`/storage/emulated/anyNumber/` points to External Storage(Android terminology) of a specific user.

**On my phone:** I have two users.

internal memory location for user1 (Ramesh) is: `/storage/emulated/0/`

internal memory location for user2 (Kishore) is: `/storage/emulated/10/`

So `/storage/emulated/legacy/` would point to `/storage/emulated/0/` if user1(Ramesh) logs in & uses the phone. In this case, `/storage/emulated/legacy/` would be a symlink to `/storage/emulated/0/`

And `/storage/emulated/legacy/` would point to `/storage/emulated/10/` if user2(Kishore) logs in & uses the phone. In this case, `/storage/emulated/legacy/` would be a symlink to `/storage/emulated/10/`

If you want to know more about storage paths, please go through this [answer on android.stackexchange.com](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/39546/42290)

I specifically mentioned *External Storage(**Android terminology**)* above. Because, the Internal and External Storage **terminology** according to Google/official Android documentation is **quite different** to that of normal Android OS user.

Comment: Very well explained. Thank you. :-)